# Conditional dependsOn

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to add a `dependsOn` with an `if` condition but the false value also needs to return a valid resource (it can't be null or empty) the resource it depends on exists in all environments. The resource with the `dependsOn` below should only be evaluated when the environment is production. How do I go about this? Here's the depends on:

```
 "dependsOn": [
        "[if(equals(parameters('environment'), 'prod'), resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName')), json('null'))]",
      ],
```

I was hoping the above would work but it doesn't! Please note, there's also a `condition` on the resource itself but the `resourceId` get's evaluated either way so I can't get past the validation.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do this, you just specify the resources you depend on, if some of them are conditioned to not deploy - nothing will break